# Python Pandas inserting new rows with colums values

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm doing a python script to clean a CSV file we receive from Qualtrics for an entrepreneurship competition.

So far, I've sliced the data and I wrote it back in an Excel file with Pandas. However, I have some columns that I would need to create new rows with. 
For example for each team submission we have

```
       Team Name    Nb of teammates   Team Leader One    Team Leader Two      
 1       x                2                Joe              Joey
 2       y                1                Jack
 ...
```

I would need to return

```
       Team Name    Nb of teammates   Team Leader          
 1       x                2                Joe             
 2                                         Joey                 
 3       y                1                Jack
 ...
```

This is a very simplified example of the real data I have, because there's more column, but I was wondering how I could do that in Pandas/Python.

I'm aware of these discussions on [Inserting Row](http://Is%20it%20possible%20to%20insert%20a%20row%20at%20an%20arbitrary%20position%20in%20a%20dataframe%20using%20pandas?) and [Indexing: Setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement), but I don't know what should I do.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: where does Yang come from?

Comment: My bad Yang doesnt matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use melt:

```
#set up frame
df =pd.DataFrame({'Team Name':['x','y'], 'Nb of teammates':[2,1], 'Team Leader One':['Joe','Jack'],'Team Leader Two':['Joey',None]})
```

Melt the frame:

```
pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Team Name','Nb of teammates'],value_vars=['Team Leader One','Team Leader Two']).dropna()
```

returns:

```
   Team Name    Nb of teamates  variable            value
0   x           2               Team Leader One     Joe
1   y           1               Team Leader One     Jack
2   x           2               Team Leader Two     Joey
```

Comment: Then I guess i can sort by Team name to realign them ?